# Logging to custom file is not working from module helper

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I wanted to wrap the logging functionality in my module helper.

**I have defined Custom Logger as:**

File: app/code/MagePsycho/CustomLogger/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_CustomLogger
 * @author     magepsycho@gmail.com
 * @website    http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="MagePsychoCustomLogger" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="debug" xsi:type="object">MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Logger\Handler\Custom</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <!-- DI for Module Observer -->
    <type name="MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Observer\ControllerActionPredispatch">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">MagePsychoCustomLogger</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <!-- DI for Module Helper -->
    <type name="MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper\Data">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">MagePsychoCustomLogger</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

File: app/code/MagePsycho/CustomLogger/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
namespace MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper;
/**
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_CustomLogger
 * @author     magepsycho@gmail.com
 * @website    http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_logger;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList
    ) {
        $this->_logger                  = $logger; //$context->getLogger();
        $this->_moduleList              = $moduleList;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Logging Utility
     *
     * @param $message
     * @param bool|false $useSeparator
     */
    public function log($message, $useSeparator = false)
    {
        //Even this is not working
        #$this->_logger->pushHandler( new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( '/var/log/magepsycho_customlogger.log') );
        if ($useSeparator) {
            $this->_logger->addDebug(str_repeat('=', 100));
        }
        $this->_logger->addDebug($message);
    }
}
```

And trying to use as (from any observer, model, block classes)

```
/**
  * @var \MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper
  */
 protected $_helper;

 public function __construct(
     \MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper\Data $helper
 ) {
     $this->_helper          = $helper;
 }
```

And call it from any methods

```
$this->_helper->log('message to be logged...');
```

But this is always logging to `var/log/debug.log` file.
If I use directly use the logger as DI, it works. But I wanted the logging functionality via Helper class.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

You can find the sample module that I am using for custom logger:
https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-custom-logger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.
The issue was related with the Constructor DI `$logger` in `\MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper\Data`.

**Solution:**
Renaming the `$logger` to `$customLogger` in the Helper class and di.xml fixed the issue.

Updated working code can be found at: 
https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-custom-logger

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the issue

I debuged the code source of the extension then i found that when you called

### `$this->_helper->log('something', true);`

from an other class

$this->_helper call the class **Magento\Backend\Helper\Data** not the **\MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper\Data**

I solved the problem by renaming **$_helper** var to something else.

**To resolve your problem**

uncomment this line

`$this->_logger->pushHandler( new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( '/var/log/magepsycho_customlogger.log') );`

in this file `\MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper\Data`

to be like

`$this->_logger->pushHandler( new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( 'var/log/magepsycho_customlogger.log') );`

**NB:** There is an other solution more simple to use custom logs

[Logs and Magento 2](https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/logs-and-magento-2/)

Comment: I renamed the $_helper in Observer to $_customLoggerHelper but still not working for me.

Comment: To resolve your problem

uncomment this line

`$this->_logger->pushHandler( new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( '/var/log/magepsycho_customlogger.log') );`

in this file `\MagePsycho\CustomLogger\Helper\Data`

to be like

`$this->_logger->pushHandler( new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( 'var/log/magepsycho_customlogger.log') );`

Comment: `var/log/...` not `/var/log/...`

Comment: Event that didn't help. but full path(absolute path) did help.

Comment: It works for me with `var/log/magepsycho_customlogger.log`

Comment: NB: There is an other solution more simple to use custom logs

 [Logs and Magento 2](https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/logs-and-magento-2/)

Comment: I tried so many approaches but nothing is working for me :(. Is it working for you for this https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-custom-logger? Happy to merge your PR if it's working.

Comment: yes it worket for me, and i already made a pull request 44 minutes ago.

Did you use any IDE to debug your code .?

Send to me your code to test it